# MySQL ON DUPLICATE insert into another table

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have the following problem:
Every author has a name and n-aliases for this name. Every alias comes from a source. Every alias has m sources. For example

```
AUTHOR| ALIAS | SOURCE
-------------------------
Will| Willy |George
Will| Bill  | Jenny
William| Will|  Francis
William| Bill| Maya
```

I have one table for the author and his name, one for all of his aliases:

```
CREATE TABLE alias (
    authors_id INT NOT NULL,
    alias VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY (author_id,alias);
```

id serves as foreign key.
Here's the second table for the sources

```
CREATE TABLE alias_source (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    source VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    alias_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    FOREIGN KEY (alias_id) REFERENCES alias(id);
```

Now I need an MySQL insert statement for when I insert 
author,alias,source into alias that the source is inserted into alias_source.
And on duplicate alias no only a new source is added.

Answer (score 0):

An INSERT statement in SQL can only insert into one table, and can only list columns of that one table. You can't include your `source` column in the INSERT statement, because it's not a column of the `alias` table.

Triggers can allow you to insert into a secondary table, but the trigger needs to know the value to insert. In this case the trigger doesn't have any way of getting the value for `source`.

This is a task that is much easier to do with two INSERT statements.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO alias SET author_id = ?, alias = ?;
INSERT INTO alias_source ...
```

But you have a problem because your `alias` table has an auto-increment column `id`, but this column is not part of a key. In InnoDB, you must make the auto-increment column the first column of a key.

Your `alias_source` table has a foreign key referencing `alias(id)` but that's not allowed. A foreign key must reference a key of the parent table. It should reference the unique or primary key, and should reference all columns of the key (otherwise you get a row in a child table that might reference multiple rows in the parent table, and that makes no sense).

If you want to use an auto-increment column for your `alias` table, make it the primary key, and put a secondary UNIQUE constraint on the other columns.

```
CREATE TABLE alias (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    authors_id INT NOT NULL,
    alias VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (author_id,alias));
```

Then query the `id` after you insert. Whether you inserted a new row, or the row already existed, you'll get the `id` for the row with the chosen author and alias.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO alias SET author_id = ?, alias = ?;
SELECT id FROM alias WHERE author_id = ? AND alias = ? INTO @id;
INSERT INTO alias_source SET alias_id = @id, source = ?;
```

---

Re your followup question in comment:

Good idea, but it doesn't work the way you may think it does. You can do a dummy set of `id=id` and set a session variable as a side effect.

```
mysql> insert into alias set author_id=1, alias='alias' 
    on duplicate key update id = @id:=id;

mysql> select @id;
+------+
| @id  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

But why didn't it set the session variable to the id? Because this insert was *not* a duplicate, it was a new row. So the `id` value had not yet been generated by auto-increment at the time the IODKU executed.

If you subsequently do the same IODKU for a row that *is* a duplicate, the `id` value has previously been added to the row, so you get the value in the side-effect:

```
mysql> insert into alias set author_id=1, alias='alias' 
    on duplicate key update id = @id:=id;

mysql> select @id;
+------+
| @id  |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

So you'd have to write application code anyway to check if `@id` is NULL or not, and do a `SELECT id` query if `@id` is NULL.

That seems more complicated than just doing the `SELECT id` as a standard action following the `INSERT IGNORE` like I showed above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer@bill!  But is it possible to use ON DUPLICATE KEY and store the duplicate id in @id?  To skip the second statement?